# ArcGIS runtime sdk for android

Tags: java, android, arcgis

I want to use ArcGIS runtime sdk in eclipse (Juno version), I followed these steps:

1. Install JDK (v1.6)
2. Install Android SDK (v1.6)
3. Install eclipse (Juno)
4. Modify Settings for android ADT in (Help-install new software...)
5. Download ArcGIS runtime SDK (zip file) and extract it, then modify settings in eclipse (help/install new software/add/ going to the directory that contain extracted zip file)

But when I want to create new "ArcGIS project for Android" this error occurred:

> proguard.cfg does not exist in C:/Program Files(86)/Android/SDK/tools/lib/proguard.cfg

and when this project is created it doesn't contain `project.properties` and `proguard.config`. How I can solve this problem? Is it necessary to install ArcGIS server?

Answer (score 0):

When i installed ArcGIS Android sdk, i didnt extract the sdk file, just keep the zip file as it is, then go to add -> archive -> browse to your zip file. Link: http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/android-sdk/concepts/index.html#//01190000002m000000